# Apply css to window popup and destroy it on focus leave in ext js

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, textbox, popover

I want to implement following functionality. The problem in below image is popup arrow should be at the edge of the textbox, how can I achieve that?

And when I click on textbox it immediately calls blur event and destroy the popup, how can I destroy popup when user clicks outside the control?

[image]
My code is as follow:

Popup

```
Ext.define('tooltip', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
displayText: '', 
xtype: 'myWin',
width: 200,
height: 50,     
layout: 'fit',
align:'center',    
cls: 'arrow-box', 
listeners: {
    show: function() {
        console.log('show');
        this.el.setStyle('left', 600); // Not applying           
    },
},
initComponent: function () {
 
    this.callParent();      
  
    this.html = '<div> hello this is test window</div>';               
},
```

Class:

```
 items: [
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    labelClsExtra: 'x-form-item-label x-required',
                    name: 'Name',
                    itemId: 'Name',
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldCls: 'big',
                    width: 650,
                    enforceMaxLength: true,
                    maxLength: 1000,                       
                    listeners: { 
                        focus: function(field) {                                
                           
                                field.suspendEvent('blur');
                                field.suspendEvent('focus');
                                
                               var displayMessage ='';
                                field.popup = field.popup  || Ext.create('tooltip',{
                                    displayText: displayMessage
                                });

                                field.popup.showBy(field.el, 'l-r');
                                field.focus();
                                field.resumeEvent('focus');
                                field.resumeEvent('blur');                                   
                            
                        },
                        blur: function(field) {
                            console.log('destroy');
                            if( field.popup != undefined &&  field.popup != null)field.popup.hide(); // It is being called immediately after focus event , so popup never comes
                        },                                                  
                 }
```

CSS

```
.arrow-box {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #859ba8;
overflow: visible;
padding: 30px;
}
.arrow-box:after, .arrow-box:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow-box:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.arrow-box:before {
  border-color: rgba(133, 155, 168, 0);
  border-right-color: #859ba8;
  border-width: 11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
}

.arrow-box .x-box-inner {
  display:none;
  height:0px !important;
}

.arrow-box .x-window-body {
  top : 0px !important;
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: do not use the show listener.

It is easier to use the `offset` from `showBy`.

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j3t) with all you answers and a propper setup of the text you want to show in the popup

```
popup.showBy(field.el, 'l-r', [10,0]);
```

Comment: Hi, @Dinkheller, thanks for the fiddle, everything is working now. However I haven't used MVC bcz my project doesn't follow MVC in ext js.  Now my popup will have buttons and links, so if click on link it will hide the popup bcz of the input blur event.

Comment: I am trying to implement something like this in blur event.
 if(ev.relatedTarget != null && (ev.relatedTarget.id !== 'tooltipId' || ev.relatedTarget.parentNode.id !== 'tooltipId')){
                                    if( field.popup != undefined &&  field.popup != null)field.popup.hide();                                  
                                 }
                            },

I am not sure whether this is the correct way or not. And when user clicks on button (do not show again) I need respective field in button click event because I need to store it's value in localstorage.

Comment: Did you update your fiddle?

Comment: Hi @Dinkheller, here it is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3j50) . I am not sure how can I integrate it with app..js, sorry I am pretty new with Ext js